# In Overwatch coop can we make heavy assault fall off cliff?

Tags: overwatch

Heavy assault often charge at us. Can we do matador style and get out just in time?

Also some heroes like Doomfist or Junkrat or Lucio or Pharah can knock people out of cliff.

Can this be done to Heavy assault?

Any video showing this? I know carrier tried to do this and fail. I wonder if heavy assault have a property "can't fall of cliff" or something. I also know many regular soldiers can be pushed off cliff by doomfist.

Answer (score 2):

Blizzard have put a number of protective measures in place to make sure heavy assaults can't simply be wiped out like that.

1. He cannot be moved with crowd control abilities like Pharah's Concussive Blast, Lucio's Soundwave, Orisa's Halt or Reinhardt's Charge.
2. When the heavy assault charges, if that charge would end up traveling out of bounds, such as into the water, he will simply stop and end his charge early instead if falling in*.  I presume the areas where the heavy assaults spawn in the mission maps have a number of blocking volumes set up specifically to prevent this. Additionally, on Retribution, if a heavy assault goes up onto the top floor of the central building and charges in a direction where there isn't a wall, he will stop rather than charge off the building, even though that fall wouldn't be fatal.

*If a player is being pinned when he stops, they will be released but keep the momentum they previously had, which normally results in them being thrown into the water unless they have a movement ability.

Comment: any sources? How do you know

Comment: The source is my own personal experience. :) I've been playing Overwatch since before Retribution first came out so I've played the missions a lot, with nearly all heroes. The blocking volumes is an educated guess since it's easier to add them into the maps manually than develop a super smart AI that can detect or avoid drops.

Comment: several player-based forums approve that heavy assaulters are somehow immune to knockback effects and other displacements like Reinhardt's Charge or the Chain Hook. On the other side, they seem to suffer longer from stun effects, like McCree's flashbang or Brigitte's Shield Bash. My personal fav pick against them is Roadhog, where you can abuse the knockback immunity to inflict tremendous damage with your Whole Hog that would otherwise push your enemies out of your efficient range

Comment: Agreed! If you can get a teammate to distract them then a nanohog in the back can be devastating.

Comment: Another strategy against heavy assaulters may be Mei, as they are not immune to _frozen_ status. However due to their large HP pool Mei would have to fully conentrate on freezing while the other team members have to do the damage job. Plus her self-healing cryostasis makes her way more durable than other DPS and her Ice Wall can be used to block him out of a brief moment or even counter his charge-like attacks. Mei is however prone to Talon Snipers.

Comment: @BoffinBrain on higher difficulties the Talon Enforcers will become a serious challenge as they deal deadly damage to almost every DPS hero and have a considerable HP pool too. Again Roadhog can perform almost the best amongst the tanks, as he also deals much damage at short range and is able to taunt them better and longer than other tank characters.